# Uploading a database to server

Tags: database, upload, server, local, host

How do I upload to my local host database to a server uses direct admin.
I tried to take a `.gz` file from my local host database and when uploading it to the server It said that it is not a backup database. So do I have to create the database tables and columns by my own self not by uploading it?

Comment: Makes no sense to me to merely upload files and expect them to work without a schema.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In **`Direct Admin`** Under **`MySQL management`**, Create a new MySQL database and user with sufficient privileges.

Go to **`PHPmyAdmin`**, Select the database you just created and choose the **`import`** tab. Upload the gz file and hit Go! The localhost database tables are now in your server.